# Prevent ngResource from requiring a returned item on $save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

It seems that when I $save or use a custom $update (put or post) method on my resource that it expects the newly posted document to be returned. I don't want to return anything from my save/post ops but an ok/200/error type of statement but doing so causes the item to be blank as soon as saved.

```
var item = Things.get({
 id: $route.current.params.id
}, function() {
 console.log(item);  // Item is ok
}); 

var item = Things.get({
 id: $route.current.params.id
}, function() {
 console.log(item);  // Item is blank (because server returned just 'ok')
 item.$save();
});
```

Comment: What are you returning form the backend when $save()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `$save()` there will be a [validation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L513) to check if there is any data returned and if thats the case, the response will be [copied](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L30) to the original object (in your case `item`)

This is the callback when receiving a response from server:

```
var promise = $http(httpConfig).then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data,
      promise = value.$promise;

  if (data) {
    // Need to convert action.isArray to boolean in case it is undefined
    // jshint -W018
    if (angular.isArray(data) !== (!!action.isArray)) {
      throw $resourceMinErr('badcfg', 'Error in resource configuration. Expected ' +
        'response to contain an {0} but got an {1}',
        action.isArray?'array':'object', angular.isArray(data)?'array':'object');
    }
    // jshint +W018
    if (action.isArray) {
      value.length = 0;
      forEach(data, function(item) {
        value.push(new Resource(item));
      });
    } else {
      shallowClearAndCopy(data, value);
      value.$promise = promise;
    }
  }

  value.$resolved = true;

  response.resource = value;

  return response;
}, function(response) {
  value.$resolved = true;

  (error||noop)(response);

  return $q.reject(response);
});
```

You can check full source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js)

So if you don't want to have your object overwritten, then just don't send any data on the response from server.

Comment: With POST requests, not sending any response can cause the server to hang and you will have PENDING requests building up in your browser

Answer (score 0):

If your server returns a 204 (no-content), it won't replace the resource once the save is complete.